# Scroll a CollectionView to ItemGroup

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `CollectionView` with groups. Each group has a string with a Date.

I subsequently created a `CarouselView` with all the dates of the `CollectionView` groups.

I am trying to create a way to scroll the elements of the `CarouselView` and consequently scroll the `CollectionView` to the corresponding group, but it doesn't work.

The `CollectionView` remains stationary.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CollectionDiary"....../>
```

**c#**

```
public class HumorGroup : ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>
{
     public string Name { get; private set; }

     public HumorGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> icon) : base(icon)
     {
         Name = name;
     }
}

public ObservableCollection<HumorGroup> TotHumor { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<HumorGroup>();

HumorGroup group = new HumorGroup("Month" + " " + Year, new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>());  

TotHumor.Add(group);
group.Add(item HumorDiary);

 private void ScrollCollectionView_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var current = CarouselView.CurrentItem as HumorGroup;
     CollectionDiary.ScrollTo(current, position: ScrollToPosition.Start);
 }
```

Comment: I would try finding the first item in the group and scrolling to that

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a way to scroll the elements of the CarouselView and consequently scroll the CollectionView to the corresponding group, but it doesn't work.

I agree with Jason's opinion, you can let CollectionView to scroll to the first item for current group in the CarouselView_Scrolled event.

```
 private void CarouselView_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = CarouselView1.CurrentItem as HumorGroup;
        if(current!=null)
        {             
            CollectionDiary.ScrollTo(current.FirstOrDefault(),ScrollToPosition.Center);
        }
        
    }
```

I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
<StackLayout>
        <CarouselView
            x:Name="CarouselView1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding humors}"
            Scrolled="CarouselView_Scrolled">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        </CarouselView>
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="CollectionDiary"
            HeightRequest="100"
            IsGrouped="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding humors}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding count}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label
                        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="Large"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page8 : ContentPage
{
    public GroupHumorViewmodel groups { get; set; }
    public Page8()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        groups = new GroupHumorViewmodel();
        this.BindingContext =groups;
    }

    private void CarouselView_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = CarouselView1.CurrentItem as HumorGroup;
        if(current!=null)
        {             
            CollectionDiary.ScrollTo(current.FirstOrDefault(),ScrollToPosition.Center);
        }
        
    }
}

public class HumorDiary
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class HumorGroup:ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>
{
    public string Name { get;  set; }
    public HumorGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> humor) : base(humor)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class GroupHumorViewmodel
{
    public ObservableCollection<HumorGroup> humors { get; set; }

    public GroupHumorViewmodel()
    {          
        humors = new ObservableCollection<HumorGroup>();
        humors.Add(new HumorGroup("2021",new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>() {
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day1",count=3},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day2",count=3},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day3",count=4},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day4",count=2},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day5",count=5},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day6",count=4},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day7",count=2},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2021-day8",count=5}


        }));

        humors.Add(new HumorGroup("2020", new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>() {
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day1",count=3},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day2",count=3},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day3",count=4},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day4",count=2},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day5",count=5},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day6",count=4},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day7",count=2},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2020-day8",count=5}


        }));

        humors.Add(new HumorGroup("2019", new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>() {
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day1",count=3},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day2",count=3},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day3",count=4},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day4",count=2},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day5",count=5},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day6",count=4},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day7",count=2},
            new HumorDiary(){name="2019-day8",count=5}


        }));
      
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need the CollectionView to scroll up to the group name and not the first element because some groups can be empty

Comment: @trecchino From [ItemsView.ScrollTo Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemsview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ItemsView_ScrollTo_System_Object_System_Object_Xamarin_Forms_ScrollToPosition_System_Boolean_), we could find that we need to specify a specific Item to jump to that place. There is feature request about [CollectionView scroll to group heading](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10721) on github.